# Use onClick twice without erasing current page content

Tags: javascript, html

I am an absolute beginner at this. This class is required for my business degree. So I apologize if this question sounds stupid.

I basically need to make a simple BMI calculator webpage.

The top of the webpage has BMI calculator and then below it has a button that is called calculate bmi and prompts users for height and weight. Then, it displays the result along with the user entered height and white.

The problem is when it displays the results it erases the BMI writing at the top.

I know their is a simple answer I just don't know what it is.

Here is the code I've been working with - http://pastebin.com/ftrWYU6L

Answer (score 1):

See the [W3C WSC](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills) (specifically the sections on traversing the DOM and modifying HTML).

`document.write` will blow any existing document away, you want to use DOM to modify the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using document.write, create a div, give it an ID like "results" or so
then on JavaScript you're going to use document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = a string containing what you would write to the screen;

here is a quick, dirty and untested fix: http://pastebin.com/2NLrMUFh

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting the whole webpage in the button.  Instead, this would typically be done with 3 text boxes (input tags in html) and one button built into the webpage.  The button would take the .value from the height and weight input boxes and store the result into the BMI.value field.

in pseudocode,

```
button_click()
{
  float height = heightTextBox.value;
  float weight = weightTextBox.value;
  float BMI = BMImojo(height, weight);  // yours to write
  BMITextBox.value = BMI;
}
```

The webpage doesn't get rebuilt, just the one output display changes